# How to bounce object off wall based off edge of shape instead of center of shape?

Tags: python, pygame

At the bottom is my full code that bounces a ball around a screen, each bounce on a wall changes color and size of ball. It is bouncing a ball off the edges of the screen based on the center of the ball. How can I modify my code so that it bounces off the edge of the ball instead? I have tried having the ball bounce if >= to the width/height of the screen minus the current radius to no avail, for example:

```
if ball_obj.left <= 0 or ball_obj.right >= width-radius:
```

Ball bouncing off edge of screen based on center of ball rather than edge of ball, shown in image:
[image: Bouncing ball]

Please and thank you for any help!

```
import pygame
#initialize game
pygame.init()

#define width of screen
width = 500
#define height of screen
height = 500

screen_res = (width, height)

pygame.display.set_caption("bouncingball")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_res)

black = (0,0,0)

#define ball
Rad = 10
maxRadius = 250
color = [(255,0,0), (255,127,0), (255,255,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255), (75, 0, 130), (128,0,211)]
i=0

ball_obj = pygame.draw.circle(
    surface = screen, color = color[i], center=[250,250], radius=Rad)

#define speed of ball
#speed = [X direction speed, Y direction speed]
x=0
y=1
speed = [x,y]
speedMultipler = -1.01

#game loop
while True:
    #event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    #fill black color on screen
    screen.fill(black)        

    #move the ball
    #let center of ball is 100,100 and the speed is (1,1)
    ball_obj = ball_obj.move(speed)
    #now center of ball is (101,101)
    #in this way our wall will move
    if Rad >= maxRadius:
        if ball_obj.left <= 0 or ball_obj.right >= width:
            if speed[0] > 70 or speed[0] < -70:
                speed[0] = -speed[0]
                if i == 6:
                    i = -1
                i+=1
                pygame.draw.circle(surface=screen, color=color[i],
                       center=ball_obj.center, radius=Rad)
            else:    
                speed[0] *= speedMultipler
                if i == 6:
                    i = -1
                i+=1
                pygame.draw.circle(surface=screen, color=color[i],
                       center=ball_obj.center, radius=Rad)

        if ball_obj.top <= 0 or ball_obj.bottom >= height:
            if speed[1] > 70 or speed[1] < -70:
                speed[1] = -speed[1]
                if i == 6:
                    i = -1
                i+=1
                pygame.draw.circle(surface=screen, color=color[i],
                       center=ball_obj.center, radius=Rad)
            else:   
                speed[1] *= speedMultipler
                if i == 6:
                    i = -1
                i+=1
                pygame.draw.circle(surface=screen, color=color[i],
                       center=ball_obj.center, radius=Rad)
    else:
        if ball_obj.left <= 0 or ball_obj.right >= width:
            speed[0] *= speedMultipler
            Rad*=1.05
            if i == 6:
                i = -1
            i+=1
            pygame.draw.circle(surface=screen, color=color[i],
                       center=ball_obj.center, radius=Rad)

        if ball_obj.top <= 0 or ball_obj.bottom >= height:
            speed[1] *= speedMultipler
            Rad*=1.05
            if i == 6:
                i = -1
            i+=1
            pygame.draw.circle(surface=screen, color=color[i],
                       center=ball_obj.center, radius=Rad)

    #draw ball at new centers that are obtain after moving ball_obj
    pygame.draw.circle(surface=screen, color=color[i],
                       center=ball_obj.center, radius=Rad)
    
    #update screen
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: `pygame` has special class `pygame.Rect()` to keep position and size - and it has special function to check collisions.

Comment: if you vertical and horizontal walls then you can check using `rectangle` because ball can touch walls only on `.left`, `.right`, `.top`, `.bottom` and it doesn't need to other other points on circle.

Comment: I don't understand why you check `ball_obj.right >= width-radius:`. As for me it should be `ball_obj.right >= width`. It doesn't need to use `radius` at all. But if you change `radius` then you have to change `width`, `height` of `ball_obj`

Comment: @furas .right = center+radius? If so I understand what you mean, but still my program shows the ball bouncing off halfway through the ball instead of the edge.

Comment: Does changing radius not change height and width? In declaration of `ball_obj` I only set the radius, and during drawing of new position I set `radius` to new `radius`

Comment: but inside loop you have `pygame.draw.circle(...)` and it does't change size because you don't have `ball_obj = ...`. You need again `ball_obj = pygame.draw.circle(...)` to change size.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the ball has collided with the screen you can use the following conditions:

```
#Check if ball collided with left of screen
if ball_obj.center[0]-radius <= 0:
    #do something

#Check if ball collided with top of screen
if ball_obj.center[1]-radius <= 0:
    #do something

#Check if ball collided with right of screen
if ball_obj.center[0]+radius >= width:
    #do something

#Check if ball collided with bottom of screen
if ball_obj.center[1]+radius >= height:
    #do something
```

Or, if you don’t want the radius, you can use huge default .left, .right, .top and .bottom values. Example code:

```
#Check if ball collided with left of screen
if ball_obj.left <= 0:
    #do something

#Check if ball collided with top of screen
if ball_obj.top <= 0:
    #do something

#Check if ball collided with right of screen
if ball_obj.right >= width:
    #do something

#Check if ball collided with bottom of screen
if ball_obj.bottom >= height:
    #do something
```

Comment: instead of `center[0]` and `center[1]` you can use `centerx`, `centery`. But I think `ball_obj.center[0]-radius` will have the same value as `ball_obj.left`, and `ball_obj.center[0]+radius` the same value as `ball_obj.right`, etc. and the same with other calculations and `ball_obj.top`, `ball_obj.bottom`

Answer (score 0):

Before loop you use `ball_obj = pygame.draw.circle(...)`

But you forgot `ball_obj = ...` inside loop when you run `pygame.draw.circle(...)`
and it doesn't change size in `ball_obj`.

You need (again) in loop:

```
ball_obj = pygame.draw.circle(...)
```

and it should change size and you may use it without `radius`

```
if ball_obj.left <= 0:
   ball_obj.left = 0  # stop on wall
   # ...

if ball_obj.right >= width:
   ball_obj.right = width  # stop on wall
   # ...

if ball_obj.top <= 0:
   ball_obj.top = 0  # stop on wall
   # ...

if ball_obj.bottom <= height:
   ball_obj.bottom = height  # stop on wall
   # ...
```

Comment: ok @furas, I have changed all code to reflect what you are saying. I am still seeing the ball bounce halfway through the circle instead of the edge.

Comment: Link to view what I am seeing. https://imgur.com/a/7Ksz1EQ

Comment: View updated code in edited post,  @furas

Comment: when you detect collision then you have to move it back to keep inside window. Maybe it is not idea but you can assign `0` or `width` or `height` because it is fast and probably nobody will see difference. I add this in my answer. For more precise you would have to change both values `x` and `y` at the same time - and it may need to use proportions. Because it gives shorter move so it would need to change time to next frame - but usually people will no see difference if you don't change time.